# Using array getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm using this scope for parsing json data:

```
$.getJSON(geocodingAPI, function (json) {

    // Set the variables from the results array
    var address = json.results[0].formatted_address;
    console.log('Address : ', address);

    var latitude = json.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
    console.log('Latitude : ', latitude);

    var longitude = json.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
    console.log('Longitude : ', longitude);

    // Set the table td text
    $('#address').text(address);
    $('#latitude').text(latitude);
    $('#longitude').text(longitude);
});
```

It works for one item, but I need to iterate all data onto my page. I'm new to this and would like to know how can I iterate the data and display more than just the first item?

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5pjha/)**

Comment: I only see a single result in that json.

Comment: Do you mean that you have multiple geocodingAPI objects of the same forme or multiple datas i mean more then just Address, Latitude, Longitude ?

Answer (score 0):

In javascript there are many ways to iterate over an array of objects, you can use for example a [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method like this:

```
$.getJSON(geocodingAPI, function (json) {

    json.results.forEach( function (item) {

        var address = item.formatted_address;
        console.log('Address : ', address);

        var latitude = item.geometry.location.lat;
        console.log('Latitude : ', latitude);

        var longitude = item.geometry.location.lng;
        console.log('Longitude : ', longitude);

        // ...

    });

});
```

Comment: You shoudl use `element` instead of `json.results[0]` inside the `forEach`